# Updating data from Bitcoin exchange API in Tkinter using Python

Tags: python, api, tkinter, auto-update

I wrote a little program using Tkinter to print out the price of Bitcoin from different exchange API. I want to be able to update the data each x seconds but I can't figure out how. My guess is I'll need to use the **`.after( delay_ms, callback, args )`** method.

**Am I right?**

```
# Python 2.7.6. Calling exchange APIs.
import time, json, requests

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def bitstampUSD():  
    bitstampUSDTick = requests.get( 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/' )
    return bitstampUSDTick.json()['last']

def btceUSD():
    btceBtcTick = requests.get( 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker' )
    return btceBtcTick.json()['ticker']['last']

bitstampUSDLive = float( bitstampUSD() )
btceUSDLive     = float( btceUSD() )

photo        = PhotoImage( file = './images/blackcoin_500_small.gif' )
text1        = Text( root, height = 30, width = 31 )
text1.insert(       END,'\n' )
text1.image_create( END, image = photo )
text1.pack( side = LEFT )

text2        = Text( root, height = 30, width = 60 )
scroll       = Scrollbar( root, command = text2.yview )
text2.configure( yscrollcommand = scroll.set )
text2.tag_configure( 'bold_italics',  font = ( 'Arial',           12, 'bold', 'italic' ) )
text2.tag_configure( 'bold',          font = ( 'Arial',           12, 'bold' ) )
text2.tag_configure( 'big',           font = ( 'Verdana',         20, 'bold' ) )
text2.tag_configure( 'medium',        font = ( 'Verdana',         14, 'bold' ) )
text2.tag_configure( 'color',         font = ( 'Tempus Sans ITC', 12, 'bold' ), foreground = '#476042' )
text2.tag_bind( 'follow', '<1>', lambda e, t = text2: t.insert( END, "Not now, maybe  later!" ) )

text2.insert( END, '\nCrypto Price Ticker\n',    'big' )
text2.insert( END, "\nBitcoin Exchange Rates\n", "medium" )
text2.insert( END, "%.2f" % bitstampUSDLive )
text2.insert( END, " USD - Bitstamp\n" )
text2.insert( END, "%.2f" % btceUSDLive )
text2.insert( END, " USD - BTC-e\n" )
text2.pack(  side = LEFT )
scroll.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, Tkinter `.after()` method will ( may ) help, but be careful.

Tkinter has a very powerful internal event-based and time-based scheduling service.

Due care ought to be taken once designing time-based and chained-scheduling scenarios for mixed GUI + non-GUI activities. It is an often case, that ill-chained request and/or a poor scheduling logic may destroy/hang the Tkinter `.mainloop()` scheduler.

Some prior experience with near-real-time system designs will help a lot to achieve both a responsive GUI-part and "well-oiled" / error-handled non-GUI-part, that will not de-stabilise both the Tkinter `.mainloop()` and the remote-data API providers' interfaces.

```
.after( wms, TASK, *args ) # non-GUI, pure MVC-Controller time-based TASK scheduling
.after_idle( TASK, *args ) # IMPORTANT method to defer a TASK into MVC-idle-<STATE>
.after_cancel( aTaskID )   # IMPORTANT method to release a scheduled TASK
.update_idletasks()        # IMPORTANT method to enforce to process TASK(s) ( if any ) deferred into an idle-tasks-queue before next MVC-idle-<STATE>
```

### Going a step behind a question "Am I right?"

Using Tkinter for both GUI layer services and for its timing ( scheduling ) services is quite a common practice.

Your principal design shall separate sub-tasks in to an event-driven mode of control ( as once you enter the `.mainloop()` this is your only resort to still remain in control of your non-GUI "*background*" activities ).

As you redesign the process into a control of the processing in disjunct "layers" ( only one of which is an already `def`-ed background Bitcoin Exchange API dialogue ) you will also need to provide means & controls for updates into the pure GUI-part of the code ( most probably via `.StringVar()`, `IntVar()`, `.BooleanVar()`, `.DoubleVar()` and their associated triggering `.trace_variable()` tools ).

For sending a non-GUI asynchronous event as a code-driven Tkinter stimulus, there is also a powerful method of `.event_generate( <eventNameId>, **args )`.

Another sign of a good real-time design is that it shall reduce traffic. A state-full design will, as a trivial example, avoid GUI re-paints in all cases, where no change or identical value(s) are retrieved from the external data-source or produced from internal processing.

### Ask for a synchronous Refresh or process a Stream Of Quotes?

There is always a chance to schedule a call for a synchronous refresh of a Bitcoin Exchange API-provided value. This will not be a trouble in case of a loose-timing design. Going faster will however start to create new problems. Some technical ( fair-queue scheduling, transport latencies, response end-to-end latencies ) and some non-technical.

For processing of remote quote-streams or quote-publishing API(s), one may also bear in mind the official Terms & Conditions applicable for the data-access. Some API have their server-side rate-limit controls, some do not, some silently drop the sessions, some will put you on a black-list for a violation of those Terms & Conditions.

Using a Stream Of Quotes processing, where offered from the Exchange, may avoid falling in conflicts with Terms & Conditions, upon growing refresh-rates and/or tighter-timing, each of which is a common trap if not handled with due care in an early design phase.

Comment: This statement isn't correct: `IMPORTANT method to defer GUI update into MVC-idle-<STATE>`. calling `update_idletasks` doesn't defer anything. Quite the opposite -- it handles any requests that have already been deferred and are sitting in the idle queue.

Comment: It's still not 100% correct. It doesn't enforce an "update" per se, only an update of items in the idle queue. Using "update" unqualified implies it's the same as calling `update`, which it is not. It only processes items in the idle event queue.

Comment: In reply to your edit remark, with this level of over-formatting, I'm afraid the odd mistake will happen. As I have indicated before, any mistakes I make are not deliberate, and I am sure you will catch them! Again, if you can reduce your overall levels of over-formatting in your new posts, that will help readability, and reduce the likelihood of mistakes in future edits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. If you want to call some function periodically, use `after`, and then have the function use `after` to reschedule itself.

For example, if you have a function named `getRates` and you want to call that approximately every 15 seconds you would write it like this:

```
def getRates():
    # put the code here to get the rates
    ...

    # call this function again as soon as possible after 15 seconds has elapsed
    root.after(15000, getRates)
```

When you call this the first time, it will then run approximately every 15 seconds until you exit the program.

Bear in mind that if `getRates` is slow (and it might be if fetching data from a web service) your GUI may have moments where it's not responsive. If that's the case, you can run the `getRates` function in a thread, and have it write to a thread-safe queue. Then, you can use the same trick with after to pull the latest data off of the queue and put it in the UI.

Comment: IMHO good scheduling is the key issue. Neither threads, nor queue-processing makes **sense in trading systems context**. There is no value to have last 13 values in a thread-safe queue, if the current price is **now** somewhere **else**, than the next "hard"-scheduled 1-sec distant, **-13-queue-reads** will block/ill-step-through. Well, having changed your code into 15000 msec emphasised impact of improper scheduling policy. Variable, ad-hoc calculated `.after()` scheduling delay + `.after_cancel()` can help a bit, however the issue goes far from just a use of the Tkinter trivial methods.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is in a "trading systems context". It's just a simple program to display data from a service. Most likely, threads and fancy scheduling is simply not necessary. When it becomes necessary, the OP can ask a question about tuning the performance.

Comment: With all due respect, Bryan, the trading context is out of question correct here. The API-specs, as they are provided, have limits for asynchronous access, even if there are no trade-execute-operation instructions ( some API providers set even more restrictive API-limits once used for trade operations than on the async Quote publication API ). **So definitely this is a view any code-design shall bear in mind from the very first prototype.** No one would like to get black-listed just due to sending too many requests against the publication API. The same for getting dropped sessions etc.

Comment: @user3666197: but what you say is true of other non-trading APIs as well. Many apis limit how often you can call them, and will black-list you if you violate their terms of service.

Comment: Are you Bryan sure, the statement "it will then run every 15 seconds " is 100% correct? Both the Tkinter gives no guarantee on upper-limit of the `.after()` time, only the lower-limit ( not earlier than ), and the `getRates()` processing-delay is also not taken into account. If it were 27 seconds, that the `getRates()` spends on it's internal processing, the statement above simply proves itself to be wrong.

Comment: No, it's not 100% correct, but it's close enough for all practical purposes. Python and tkinter aren't designed for true real time systems.